# C++: How to find out used GPU of a process?

Tags: c++, windows, gpu, directx, dxgi

I want to find out which GPU is used by a process.
Since the Fall Creators Update the windows Task-Manager shows the used GPU per process:

[image]

Is there a way to get this information in C++?

I tried to search already existing solutions but did not find one. I am aware, that you can get the current adapter using [IDXGIDevice::GetAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgidevice-getadapter) but I want to get the adapter which is used by another process.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not documented. The Process Hacker tool has some undocumented knowledge about it :https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/plugins/ExtendedTools/gpumon.c